# Restart Grand Theft Auto V Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

What is the only legit/technical way you can completely reset/restart Grand Theft Auto V Online? A little while ago, my cousin purchased a ton of useless Pegasus vehicles and now I can't get rid of them so I would like to know if there is a way to restart GTA V Online completely from the beginning from $0 and level 0. For example, would the only way to legitimately restart the game be to create another Social Club and Steam account and purchase another copy of Grand Theft Auto V? Or is there another way around this? I'm not going to waste all my money on one character and then swap characters online. I want to know if there is another way around this. Please let me know if there's anything I need to clarify or elaborate on or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

When in-game press start(esc) > online > swap character, 2nd slot should be free and allow you to make a 2nd character.

You should have the choice between starting fresh or using the level and bank account from your previous character. You just have to select you do not want this.

I am not sure if you want to just start over with level and money, or also achievements. Achievements, such as the criminal mastermind, are tied to your account.